# Explanations about some Mittag-leffler partial fraction expansions

Tags: calculus, laurent-series

Is it possible to show where the following series come from?

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{\pi ^2 k^2}-\frac{2}{(x-2 \pi  k)^2}-\frac{2}{(2 \pi  k+x)^2}\right)+\left(-\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{\cos (z)-1}$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{2 \pi ^2 k^2+3}{6 \pi ^4 k^4}+\frac{2}{3 (x-2 \pi  k)^2}+\frac{4}{(x-2 \pi  k)^4}+\frac{2}{3 (2 \pi  k+x)^2}+\frac{4}{(2 \pi  k+x)^4}\right)+\frac{4}{x^4}+\frac{2}{3 x^2}+\frac{11}{180}=\frac{1}{(\cos (z)-1)^2}$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{8 \pi ^4 k^4+15 \pi ^2 k^2+15}{60 \pi ^6 k^6}-\frac{4}{15 (x-2 \pi  k)^2}-\frac{2}{(x-2 \pi  k)^4}-\frac{8}{(x-2 \pi  k)^6}-\frac{4}{15 (2 \pi  k+x)^2}-\frac{2}{(2 \pi  k+x)^4}-\frac{8}{(2 \pi  k+x)^6}\right)+\left(-\frac{8}{x^6}-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{4}{15 x^2}-\frac{191}{7560}\right)=\frac{1}{(\cos (z)-1)^3}$$ sorry for the inconvenient I forget to add a part of the formula.

Comment: Are you sure about the first one ?

Comment: maple say it is correct

Comment: Would you accept to try $x=\frac \pi 2$ in the first one ?

Comment: [Come on, I gave you the whole calculation for $\cot^k(z)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931312/expansions-of-meromorphic-functions/1931892#1931892), it works exactly the same here !!

Comment: @user1952009. Am I doing something wrong ? If not, how could Maple say that it is correct ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not sure of what you are doing, but since $\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1} = \frac{2}{z^2}+\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $z \to 0$, and $\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1} =\frac{-2}{(z-\pi)^2}+\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $z \to \pi$, you have that $\frac{1}{\cos(z)-1} - \frac{2}{z^2}+ \frac{2}{(z-\pi)^2}$  is analytic on $|z-\pi/2| < 3\pi/2$, and by $2\pi$ periodicity it means that $f(z) = \frac{1}{\cos(z)-1} - \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (\frac{2}{(z-2k\pi)^2}- \frac{2}{(z-\pi-2k\pi)^2})$ is entire, and since it is also bounded, by Liouville's theorem it is constant.

Comment: @user1952009. As I wrote, I suppose that I am doing something wrong since Maple said that it is correct. What I would like to know is : what is wrong in what I wrote (speaking about the sum from $1$ to $\infty$) ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I messed up with the sign, but the rest I wrote is correct (substract the poles, then the residual is a constant !!). And you shouldn't really care of what is wrong in your answer, since using the digamma function wasn't a good idea anyway (do it the easy way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented earlier, I have a problem with the first expression. So, since Maple said that it is correct, I suppose I am wrong but I would like to know where.

Let me consider $$S_1=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\pi ^2 k^2}\qquad S_2=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(x-2 \pi  k)^2}\qquad S_3=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{(x+2 \pi  k)^2}$$ So $$S_1=\frac 16\qquad S_2=\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{x}{2 \pi }\right)}{4 \pi ^2}\qquad S_3=\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{x}{2 \pi }\right)}{4 \pi ^2}$$ where appears the first derivative of the digamma function.$$S_1-2S_2-2S_3=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{x}{2 \pi }\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{x}{2 \pi }\right)}{2 \pi ^2}=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{\cos (x)-1}$$ the last simplification being obtained using a CAS.

Using Taylor around $x=0$, what I find is $$S_1-2S_2-2S_3=-\frac{x^2}{120}-\frac{x^4}{3024}-\frac{x^6}{86400}+O\left(x^{8}\right)$$ while $$\frac{1}{\cos (x)-1}=-\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x^2}{120}-\frac{x^4}{3024}-\frac{x^6}{86400}+O\left(x^{8}\right)$$

Comment: claude leibovici your writte i edit the formulas  i forget add a part of the formulas the laurent serie.