# Whats the correct way to factorize $x \sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$?

Tags: factoring, infinite-product

I am inspired by Euler's factorization of $sin(x)$ as an infinite product. I was trying to apply to the expression $x \sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$.

Let $f(x) = x \sin{\frac{\pi}{x}}$. My findings were as follows:

1. $f(x) = 0$ at infinitely many points in the closed interval $[-1,1]$
2. $f(x) = 0$, namely at $x = 0$, and $x = \dfrac{1}{n}, n \space \epsilon \space Z \space \& \space n \neq 0$
3. $\therefore$ we can write $f(x) = A (x - 0)(x-1)(x+1)(x-\dfrac{1}{2})(x+\dfrac{1}{2})...$

$$ \implies f(x) = A x \Pi_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)$$

We can solve for $A$ by putting $x=2$, we get $A = \frac{1}{\Pi\left(4 - \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)}$

So we get $$f(x) = x\Pi\left(\dfrac{x^2 - \frac{1}{n^2}}{4 - \frac{1}{n^2}}\right)$$

Now if we expand $f(x)$ in terms of its taylor series, we get a polynomial in powers of $\frac{1}{x}$, where as on the LHS we get powers of $x$. I can't equate coefficients as a result of this approach.

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: it isn't how it works. The proof of the infinite product for $\sin(z)$ is [by showing the partial fraction expansion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931312/) of $(\log \sin(z))' = \cot(z)$ is $ C+\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\pi n}+\frac{1}{z+\pi n}$. This is because $\cot(z)-(\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\pi n}+\frac{1}{z+\pi n})$ is a bounded entire function, so by the Liouville theorem it is constant. Evaluating at $z = \pi/2$ gives $C =0$, and going back $\sin(z) =z \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{z^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$

Comment: I just realized I got the taylor expansion wrong... :(

Comment: You should realize your product isn't convergent, while mine is (this is because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\pi n}+\frac{1}{z+\pi n}$ converges that we can prove $\cot(z) - (\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-\pi n}+\frac{1}{z+\pi n})$ is entire and bounded). A good exercice is to derive $C = 0$ and the product for $\sin(z)$ from this series for $\cot(z) = (\log(\sin(z))'$

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I guess it is non-factorisable.</strike>. We can factorize the RHS. But we cannot proceed to step of equating coefficients of terms of similar powers

Findings:

1. the function isn't differentiable at $x = 0$
2. because of the above fact taylor series of the function is impossible.

Comment: come on, I answered in the comments. $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2 n^2})$ so $\displaystyle\pi f(\pi/x) = x\sin(\pi / x) = \pi \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{x^2 n^2})$

Comment: What you have to remember that the difference between [(Weierstrass) factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) of analytic functions and factorization of polynomials is the infinite number of zeros, so there are many **convergence problems**

Comment: Please do write this as answer. Letting $a_n = 1- \frac{1}{x^2n^2}$. So your divergence assertion is that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\log{a_n}$ tends to infinity. Is that correct?

Comment: The product I wrote converges because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1-\frac{1}{x^2n^2}) $ converges (using that $\log(1-\frac{1}{x^2n^2}) \sim \frac{-1}{x^2n^2}$ as $n \to \infty$). Yours diverges because its general term doesn't $\to 1$

Comment: An infinite product is always of the form $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ where $a_n \to 0$